# How do I fix the error TypeError: can't access property "isRoot", location is undefined in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, sveltekit

I have an issue where, when I use firebase storage, I get the error:

> TypeError: can't access property "isRoot", location is undefined

I am using SvelteKit, and have tested (because location is a browser object) it in an onMount call, as well as checking the browser form $app/environment. I have found the error is caused by these lines, I believe the `listAll` function:

```js
listAll(filesRef).then((list)=>{
    list.items.forEach(item=>{
        files.push({
            filetype:item.name.split(".").at(-1).toString(),
            name:item.name
       });
    });
});
```

For context, the files variable is a list of objects with the filetype and filename.
I render these in a list.

If it helps, here's the entire traceback:

```
list$2 requests.ts:182
    list$1 reference.ts:406
    listAllHelper reference.ts:361
    listAll$1 reference.ts:343
    listAll api.ts:257
    instance +page.svelte:58
    init index.mjs:2002
    Page +page.svelte:791
    createProxiedComponent svelte-hooks.js:341
    ProxyComponent proxy.js:242
    Proxy<+page> proxy.js:349
    construct_svelte_component_dev index.mjs:2218
    update root.svelte:274
    update_slot_base index.mjs:98
    update +layout.svelte:154
    update index.mjs:1193
    flush index.mjs:1160
    promise callback*schedule_update index.mjs:1118
    make_dirty index.mjs:1970
    ctx index.mjs:2008
    $$set root.svelte:581
    get proxy.js:83
    $set index.mjs:2109
    key proxy.js:46
    update client.js:320
    navigate client.js:1077
    goto client.js:182
    goto client.js:1249
    gotoNext +page.svelte:11
    instance +page.svelte:18
    registerStateListener auth_impl.ts:565
    promise callback*registerStateListener auth_impl.ts:565
    onAuthStateChanged auth_impl.ts:407
    onAuthStateChanged index.ts:128
    instance +page.svelte:17
    run index.mjs:18
    mount_component index.mjs:1939
    flush index.mjs:1175
    promise callback*schedule_update index.mjs:1118
    make_dirty index.mjs:1970
    ctx index.mjs:2008
    $$set root.svelte:581
    get proxy.js:83
    $set index.mjs:2109
    key proxy.js:46
    update client.js:320
    navigate client.js:1077
    goto client.js:182
    goto client.js:1249
    default Goto.ts:3
    instance +page.svelte:14
    run index.mjs:18
    mount_component index.mjs:1939
    flush index.mjs:1175
    init index.mjs:2034
    Root root.svelte:633
    createProxiedComponent svelte-hooks.js:341
    ProxyComponent proxy.js:242
    Proxy<Root> proxy.js:349
    initialize client.js:374
    _hydrate client.js:1630
    start start.js:39
    <anonymous> [page]:10039
```

Comment: Can you please share complete code so we can see where `filesRef` is defined?

Comment: It's defined like so: `const filesRef = ref(`user-generated/${$user.uid}`);`, right above when I call the `listAll` function. Also: I have a store which updates when `onAuthStateChanged` fires, so maybe that is causing some sort of problem?

Answer (score 0):

### I found the problem

I figured out that, when I define the filesRef variable using the `ref` function, I forgot to define the `storage` attribute.

##### Original Definition (broken):

```js
let filesRef = ref(`/user-generated/${$user.uid}`);
```

##### New Definition (working):

```js
const storage = getStorage(app);
let filesRef = ref(storage, `/user-generated/${$user.uid}`);
```

I think that this is a bit of a problem because I spent literal hours looking for this bug. I am puzzled by the fact that it only causes an error in the `listAll` function, and not one relating to the storage parameter missing in the `ref` function. I am further puzzled that it refers to the `location` variable in the browser, as if it needs to check if the path is root, but can't do that in the event that the storage attribute is missing. I also know that `isRoot` is not a part of the location API, so maybe Firebase is extending the location API? I have used devTools to find the script and it is of the type of the window.location, so maybe Firebase should add a check for this. If this is some error that doesn't occur in JavaScript, as I'm using Typescript, but I heavily doubt this is the problem, as Typescript is complied into normal JS.